# Sequential linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

> I need some help starting this problem. I'm not sure how to put this in SLP form from the general form. And, how do I use the X^0 vector in this? For the optimization problem below, put the problem in correct SLP form for the first movement. Apply the appropriate move limits as well.
>
> $$\begin{align}
> &\min F(X) = {x_1}^3 {x_2} {x_3}^5 + 32{x_2}^4 x_1 - 20x_1 {x_3}^3 \\
> &S.T.\\
> &g_1(X) = 5{x_1}^2 + 7{x_3}^4 x_2 \le 0 \\
> &g_2(X) = \frac{{X_3}^2}{x_1} + 6x_2 \\
> &1 \le x_1 \le 9 \\
> &3\le x_2 \\
> &x_3 \le 25
> \end{align}$$
>
> The initial point is: $$X^0 = \begin{bmatrix}3\\3.03\\20\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: It would be clearer for the answerers if you included in the question what your difficulties are regarding this problem. Do you understand the problem? How are you stuck?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to put this in SLP form by using the standard SLP form. And how do I apply move limits?